# In java, the adapter between fragments is reset and formed from the beginning

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

When the fragment is first opened, the information in it is visible, when I switch between the fragments and return again, the first fragment appears empty, I think the error is that the adapter is restarted while switching between the fragments, I would appreciate if you could help.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements AddBagInterface {
    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    RecyclerViewHomeAdapter recyclerViewHomeAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbb");
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        System.out.println("ccccccccccc");
        homeViewModel.fetchProducts();

        homeViewModel.getProductsLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Store>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Store> stores) {
                displayProducts(stores);

            }
        });
    }

    private void displayProducts(List<Store> stores) {
        if (recyclerViewHomeAdapter == null) {
            System.out.println("aaaaa");
            binding.recyclerViewHome.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));
            recyclerViewHomeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter((List<Store>) stores, this);
            binding.recyclerViewHome.setAdapter(recyclerViewHomeAdapter);
        }else {
            recyclerViewHomeAdapter.setStoreList(stores);
            System.out.println("ababababa");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void addBagItems(List<Bag> bagList) {
        homeViewModel.setSelectedProducts(bagList);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),bagList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(bagList);
    }
}
```

My aim is to ensure that the page does not appear blank when I go to another fragment from the fragment with the products and return.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).